# How to properly pass useReducer actions down to children without causing unnecessary renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't quite figure out the optimal way to use `useReducer` hook for data management. My primary goal is to reduce (heh) the boilerplate to minimum and maintain code readability, while using the optimal approach in terms of performance and preventing unnecessary re-renders.

### The setup

I have created a simplified example of my app, basically it's a `<List />` component - a list of items with possibility to select them, and a `<Controls />` component which can switch item groups and reload the data set.

#### List.js

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

const List = ({ items, selected, selectItem, deselectItem }) => {
  console.log("<List /> render");

  return (
    <ul className="List">
      {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <li key={`item-${name.toLowerCase()}`}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={selected.includes(id)}
              onChange={(e) =>
                e.target.checked ? selectItem(id) : deselectItem(id)
              }
            />
            {name}
          </label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default memo(List);
```

#### Controls.js

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

import { ItemGroups } from "./constants";

const Controls = ({ group, setGroup, fetchItems }) => {
  console.log("<Controls /> render");

  return (
    <div className="Controls">
      <label>
        Select group
        <select value={group} onChange={(e) => setGroup(e.target.value)}>
          <option value={ItemGroups.PEOPLE}>{ItemGroups.PEOPLE}</option>
          <option value={ItemGroups.TREES}>{ItemGroups.TREES}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <button onClick={() => fetchItems(group)}>Reload data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(Controls);
```

#### App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

import Controls from "./Controls";
import List from "./List";
import Loader from "./Loader";

import { ItemGroups } from "./constants";

import {
  FETCH_START,
  FETCH_SUCCESS,
  SET_GROUP,
  SELECT_ITEM,
  DESELECT_ITEM
} from "./constants";

import fetchItemsFromAPI from "./api";

import "./styles.css";

const itemsReducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  console.log(`reducer action "${type}" dispatched`);

  switch (type) {
    case FETCH_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };

    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: payload.items,
        isLoading: false
      };

    case SET_GROUP:
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: state.selected.length ? [] : state.selected,
        group: payload.group
      };

    case SELECT_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: [...state.selected, payload.id]
      };

    case DESELECT_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: state.selected.filter((id) => id !== payload.id)
      };

    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown action type in items reducer");
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemsReducer, {
    items: [],
    selected: [],
    group: ItemGroups.PEOPLE,
    isLoading: false
  });

  const { items, group, selected, isLoading } = state;

  const fetchItems = (group) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });

    fetchItemsFromAPI(group).then((items) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
        payload: { items }
      })
    );
  };

  const setGroup = (group) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_GROUP,
      payload: { group }
    });
  };

  const selectItem = (id) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_ITEM,
      payload: { id }
    });
  };

  const deselectItem = (id) => {
    dispatch({
      type: DESELECT_ITEM,
      payload: { id }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect on group change");

    fetchItems(group);
  }, [group]);

  console.log("<App /> render");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Controls {...{ group, fetchItems, setGroup }} />
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <List {...{ items, selected, selectItem, deselectItem }} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the [complete sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-reducer-example-jx12j?file=/src/App.js).

The state is managed in a reducer, because I need different parts of state to work and change together. For example, reset selected items on group change (because it makes no sense to keep selections between different data sets), set loaded items and clear loading state on data fetch success, etc. The example is intentionally simple, but in reality there're many dependencies between different parts of state (filtering, pagination, etc.), which makes reducer a perfect tool to manage it - in my opinion.

I've created helper functions to perform different actions (for ex., to reload items or to select/deselect). I could just pass down the dispatch to children and create action objects there, but this turns everything into a mess really quickly, esp. when multiple components must perform same actions.

### Problem 1

Passing down reducer action functions to child components causes them to re-render on any reducer update.

- Case 1: When I select an item in `<List />`, the `<Controls />` is
  re-rendered.
- Case 2: When I reload the data on Reload button click, the `<Controls />` is
  re-rendered.

In both cases, the `<Controls />` only actually depends on `group` prop to render, so when it stays the same - the component should not re-render.

I've investigated it and this happens because on each `<App />` re-render these action functions are re-created and treated as new prop values for child components, so for React it's simple: new props => new render.

Not ideal solution to this is to wrap all action functions in `useCallback`, with dispatch as a dependency, but this looks like a hack to me.

```
const setGroup = useCallback(
  (group) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_GROUP,
      payload: { group }
    });
  },
  [dispatch]
);
```

In a simple example it does not look too bad, but when you have dozens of possible actions, all wrapped in `useCallback`, with deps arrays - that does not seem right.

And it requires to add even more deps to `useEffect` (which is another problem).

Here's a ["fixed" version](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-reducer-example-usecallback-i9nxg?file=/src/App.js) with `useCallback`.

### Problem 2

I cannot fully extract reducer action functions outside the `<App />` component, because in the end they must be used inside a React component with the `dispatch` (because it's a hook).

I can of course extract them to a separate module and pass `dispatch` as a first argument:

#### in actions.js

```
// ...
export const fetchItems = (dispatch, group) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });

  fetchItemsFromAPI(group).then((items) =>
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
      payload: { items }
    })
  );
};
// ...
```

and then in child components do this:

```
import { fetchItems } from './actions';

const Child = ({ dispatch, group }) => {
  fetchItems(dispatch, group);
  // ...
};
```

and reduce my `<App />` to this:

```
// ...
const App = () => {
  const [{ items, group, selected, isLoading }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    itemsReducer,
    itemReducerDefaults
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(dispatch, group);
  }, [group, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Controls {...{ group, dispatch }} />
      {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <List {...{ items, selected, dispatch }} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

but then I have to pass around the `dispatch` (minor issue) and always have it in arguments list. On the other hand, it fixes the Problem 1 as well, as dispatch does not change between renders.

Here's a [sandbox with actions and reducer extracted](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-reducer-example-dispatch-0zy4x).

But is it optimal, or maybe I should use some entirely different approach?

So, how do you guys use it? The React docs and guides are nice and clean with counter increments and ToDo lists, but how do you actually use it in real world apps?

Comment: Wrap your "action creators" in `useCallback` to provide a stable action callback reference, (1) because that is what it was designed for, it's not a "hack", and (2) is IMO the cleanest code of the options shown. The action creators are redeclared each render cycle. Is it an issue that some children components rerender? You should invert your actions so the `dispatch` wraps the returned action object, then you can externally define action creators and they won't be a render dependency. You can simply pass `dispatch` to children.

Comment: Yes, I also like the second approach much better, I understand that using useCallback is not a hack, but it adds too much unnecessary code, which is something I'd like to avoid. As for inverting actions - that's a good idea, but will not work for all cases, because some action functions trigger multiple actions and perform async operations. Regarding re-render - yes, I believe it's an issue. I know React does not actually modify DOM for all renders, but adding this kind of inefficiency in every part of App will eventually add up. For me, it's about knowing it doesn't do anything stupid. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-redux works by also wrapping all the actions with a call to `dispatch`; this is abstracted away when using the `connect` HOC, but still required when using the `useDispatch` hook. Async actions typically have a function signature `(...args) => dispatch => {}` where the action creator instead returns a function that accepts the dispatch function provided by redux, but redux requires middleware to handle these. Since you are not actually using Redux you'd need to handle this yourself, likely using a combination of both patterns to achieve similar usage.

I suggest the following changes:

1. De-couple and isolate your action creators, they should be functions that return action objects (or asynchronous action functions).
2. Create a custom dispatch function that handles asynchronous actions.
3. Correctly log when a component renders (i.e. during the commit phase in an `useEffect` hook and ***not*** during any render phase in the component body. See [this lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).
4. Pass the custom dispatch function to children, import actions in children... dispatch actions in children. [How to avoid passing callbacks down](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down).
5. Only conditionally render the `Loader` component. When you render one or the other of `Loader` and `List` the other is unmounted.

Actions (actions.js)

```
import {
  FETCH_START,
  FETCH_SUCCESS,
  SET_GROUP,
  SELECT_ITEM,
  DESELECT_ITEM
} from "./constants";

import fetchItemsFromAPI from "./api";

export const setGroup = (group) => ({
  type: SET_GROUP,
  payload: { group }
});

export const selectItem = (id) => ({
  type: SELECT_ITEM,
  payload: { id }
});

export const deselectItem = (id) => ({
  type: DESELECT_ITEM,
  payload: { id }
});

export const fetchItems = (group) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });

  fetchItemsFromAPI(group).then((items) =>
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
      payload: { items }
    })
  );
};
```

useAsyncReducer.js

```
const asyncDispatch = (dispatch) => (action) =>
  action instanceof Function ? action(dispatch) : dispatch(action);

export default (reducer, initialArg, init) => {
  const [state, syncDispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);
  const dispatch = React.useMemo(() => asyncDispatch(syncDispatch), []);
  return [state, dispatch];
};
```

*Why doesn't `useMemo` need a dependency on `useReducer` dispatch function?*

[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `dispatch` function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect`
> or `useCallback` dependency list.

We want to also provide a stable `dispatch` function reference.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useReducer from "./useAsyncReducer";

import Controls from "./Controls";
import List from "./List";
import Loader from "./Loader";

import { ItemGroups } from "./constants";

import {
  FETCH_START,
  FETCH_SUCCESS,
  SET_GROUP,
  SELECT_ITEM,
  DESELECT_ITEM
} from "./constants";
import { fetchItems } from "./actions";

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemsReducer, {
    items: [],
    selected: [],
    group: ItemGroups.PEOPLE,
    isLoading: false
  });

  const { items, group, selected, isLoading } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect on group change");

    dispatch(fetchItems(group));
  }, [group]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("<App /> render");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Controls {...{ group, dispatch }} />
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      <List {...{ items, selected, dispatch }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Controls.js

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { ItemGroups } from "./constants";
import { setGroup, fetchItems } from "./actions";

const Controls = ({ dispatch, group }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("<Controls /> render");
  });

  return (
    <div className="Controls">
      <label>
        Select group
        <select
          value={group}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(setGroup(e.target.value))}
        >
          <option value={ItemGroups.PEOPLE}>{ItemGroups.PEOPLE}</option>
          <option value={ItemGroups.TREES}>{ItemGroups.TREES}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchItems(group))}>Reload data</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

List.js

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { deselectItem, selectItem } from "./actions";

const List = ({ dispatch, items, selected }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("<List /> render");
  });

  return (
    <ul className="List">
      {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <li key={`item-${name.toLowerCase()}`}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={selected.includes(id)}
              onChange={(e) =>
                dispatch((e.target.checked ? selectItem : deselectItem)(id))
              }
            />
            {name}
          </label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Loader.js

```
const Loader = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("<Loader /> render");
  });

  return <div>Loading data...</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-properly-pass-usereducer-actions-down-to-children-without-causing-unneces]