# Reactjs updating a nested array inside an array of objects with useReducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-reducer

I am having a bit of trouble and think I must be making a silly mistake that I cannot see. I am trying to make a function inside of my useReducer reducer function which updates a todo.complete value to be  either true or false (this is called when clicking a checkbox). The structure is [Object].[todoList].complete: which defaults as false, but I want to change it to !complete.

The code in my reducer function is...

```
       case "UPDATE_TODO_COMPLETE":
           let updatedTask = tasksState.filtered.filter((task) => {
                if (task.id === action.payload.task.id) {
                    return {
                        ...task,
                        todoList: task.todoList.map((todo) => {
                            if (todo.id === action.payload.todo.id) {
                                alert(todo.name);
                                return { ...todo, complete: !todo.complete };
                            }
                        }),
                    };
                }
            });

            tasksAPI_POST_Task_Update(updatedTask);

            return tasksState; //change to return updated object array when above is working
```

tasksAPI_POST_Task_Update(updatedTask); will end up posting the updates to the API but currently it just does a console.log(). The object is logs back does not have an updated complete value when the above function is called.

I want to be able to update the todoList.todo in an object from an array of objects. The objects in the array look like this:

```
{
        name: "Bob's daily task",
        id: "1",
        bucketId: "1",
        setDate: "Mon May 24 2021 19:29:39 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)",
        dueDate: "Tue May 25 2021 19:29:39 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)",
        description:
            "This is a daily task which tells Bob what is needed to be done by todays EOB",
        status: 3,
        progress: 90,
        adminUsers: [
            {
                name: "Tom",
                id: "65e76cbe-07df-4c82-b94c-1e939cd3e6e5",
            },
        ],
        readOnlyUsers: [
            {
                name: "Roy",
                id: "idforroy",
            },
            {
                name: "Jack",
                id: "idforjack",
            },
        ],
        progressReports: [
            {
                id: "45987asdf87sd21sdf",
                name: "Report 1",
                date: "Mon May 24 2021 19:29:39 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)",
                user: {
                    name: "Greg",
                    id: "65e76cbe-07df-4c82-b94c-1e939cd3e6e5",
                },
                report: "There was a big stuff up and now everything is a total mess!",
            },
        ],
        todoList: [
            {
                name: "todo1",
                id: "td1",
                complete: false,
                desription:
                    "This is the first todo. It requires doing a thing, about a thing, to fix another thing, cause that thing is broken",
            },
            {
                name: "todo2",
                id: "td",
                complete: false,
                desription:
                    "This todo is complementary to the first todo. Both of these must be completed to consider the task finished",
            },
        ],
    },
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Am I missing something here? or is there an easier way  to do this?

EDITS: This makes sense about the API call function. My only reason for wanting to include it in the reducer was because this reducer is used on multiple components across my app, so I was hoping I'd be able to get call it from within the reducer.
The intialstate for the reducer is a tasks list. There are two version of this list, tasksState, which is what is fetched from the API, and filtered which is what is actually displayed in the app. I have a seperate filtered version of the data because there is sorting and search functionality which takes tasksState to produce filtered for being displayed. tasksState consists of many of the aforementioned objects. When reviewing a specific task there is a todos list, what I want to update is a single todo.complete. Though this seems to be working with:

```
return {
                ...tasksState,
                filtered: tasksState.filtered.map((task) => {
                    if (task.id === action.payload.task.id) {
                        return {
                            ...task,
                            todoList: task.todoList.map((todo) => {
                                if (todo.id === action.payload.todo.id) {
                                    return { ...todo, complete: !todo.complete };
                                } else {
                                    return todo;
                                }
                            }),
                        };
                    } else {
                        return task;
                    }
                }),
                tasksState: tasksState.tasksState.map((task) => {
                    if (task.id === action.payload.task.id) {
                        return {
                            ...task,
                            todoList: task.todoList.map((todo) => {
                                if (todo.id === action.payload.todo.id) {
                                    return { ...todo, complete: !todo.complete };
                                } else {
                                    return todo;
                                }
                            }),
                        };
                    } else {
                        return task;
                    }
                }),
            };
```

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: You've a couple major issues, starting with trying to send POST requests from a reducer function (reducer functions are supposed to be pure functions), and not returning a new `taskState` state object. You seem to unnecessarily nest a todoList array within a filtered array. Can you update your question to include your reducer's initial state so it's a little clearer what *actually* needs to be updated and returned?

Comment: Yes like drew said, the reducer is returning the next (local) state. if you just need data sending off to an API, you should think about using an effect hooks or a click handler, depending on where this change is originated from

Comment: The `filtered` array appears to be mostly "derived state" from your actual state, it doesn't really need to be stored in state, as you can tell there's a lot of code duplication (not **DRY**). Other than this, I see no issues with how you copy previous state and toggle the `complete` property. And I totally agree that the POST request should be done via a `useEffect` hook, or via an asynchronous action. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65622133/8690857) for an `useAsyncReducer` example that allows you to use a  Redux Thunk pattern with local `useReducer` state.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Drew. Thank you also for that link, very useful!
Regarding the double of state and code, is there a standardized way to store state when you have filtered data which is used for rendering?

Comment: Typically you'd store *just* your data and the value (or values) you want to filter by in state, and compute the filtered result per render. If the filtering process is "expensive" then you can memoize the result so additional rerenders won't incur an additional cost if the result will be the same as the previous render